# Where are the Ruby proxy settings on OS X?

Tags: ruby, macos, proxy, terminal, homebrew

I'm trying to install Homebrew using the command suggested on their website:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

And I get the error:

curl: (7) Failed to connect to www-proxy.xxx.com port 80: Operation timed out

Now, I am actually on a home network, so I don't want to be going through proxy. Why is it trying to do so? Is there a Ruby proxy config somewhere that's causing this?

Comment: Well, going by the "xxx" in the url I'm guessing you have some sort of hijacking going on in your network setup. In the terminal `ping google.com` and see what you get. Notice it is `www-proxy.xxx.com`, the dash is not the way most sites are set up, they are normally www.foo.com.

Comment: XXX is the placeholder for my company name.

Comment: Have you looked at your network adapter's proxy settings?

Comment: LOL! Well if you google that exact URL it is a porn site. So it sure looked like you were being redirected.

Comment: @NickVeys Yeah I got rid of my proxy settings from the network adapter.

Comment: Doesn't look like a Ruby issue. Have you tried to run the curl command without `ruby -e`? If that doesn't work either, open the URL in your browser, save the file and run it with `ruby filename`

Answer (score 2):

You should set your command proxy on the command window:

```
export http_proxy=[your proxy]
export https_proxy=[your proxy]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find proxy settings here:

```
System Preferences -> Network -> Advanced -> Proxies.
```